# Как создать файл стилей в QT Creator и интегрировать его в код C++?

Tags: c++, qt

Я создаю интерфейс непосредственно в коде, не в редакторе. Тоже хотелось бы узнать, насколько правильно иметь здоровый private из объектов интерфейса, нежели использовать обращение через ui.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: Второе, это дело вкуса и удобства, но лучше все же как-то разделять и властвовать, а то в процессе легко начать путаться что где и как

Comment: @AlexanderChernin 20 раз просматривал эту ссылку и так им не увидел, как в самом creator-е создать файл qss и работать с подстветкой синтаксиса

Comment: В самом редакторе вы можете создать текстовый файл и редактировать его непосредственно в креаторе (только не помню, есть там подсветка синтаксиса, или нет). Сам qss настолько урезан и прост, что особой подсветки ему и не нужно, но если что, всегда есть notepad++